# PHP: pass internal date() function as function parameter?

Tags: php, function, date, param

I wonder if this is possible somehow …

```
function get_event_list( $year = date('Y') ) {

    }
```

So I could call this function like `get_event_list(2012)`, but when not adding a para it always retrieves all events from the current year (2014);

Kind Regards,
Matt

Comment: According to http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/ it not ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make the parameter nullable like so:

```
function get_event_list( $year = NULL ){
  $year = is_null( $year) ? date('Y') : $year;
  //Code here
}
```

A way to call this function would be `get_event_list(2012)` or `get_event_list()`

Answer (score 4):

The best way to achieve it is to do:

```
function get_event_list( $year = null ) {
    if ( is_null($year) ) {
        $year = date('Y');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't use a built-in function as the default argument.

From the [PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.default):

> The default value must be a constant expression, not (for example) a variable, a class member or a function call.

What you need can be achieved as follows:

```
function get_event_list($year = null) {
    if(!isset($year)) {
        $year = date('Y');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

```
function get_even_list($year = ""){
    if(empty($year)){
        $year = date('Y');
    }

    // Whatever you wann do here
}
```

Steve